# Python Jinja2: How to add an empty row in a table, which is created from a nested loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I create a table from 2 for loops, and I'd like to add an empty row when each inner loop is finished.

Do I need to keep track of both outer loop and inner loop for it, like this? Or is there a better way to do it?

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    {% for dict in table_data %}
    {% set outer_loop = loop %}
        {% for test_name, test_dict in dict["tests_data"].items() %}
            ....
            {% if not outer_loop.last or not loop.last %}  <!-- Add an empty row -->
                <tr bgcolor="FFFFFF">
                    <td colspan="{{titles|length}}"><br/></td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Im finding this a bit confusing to follow, you want to create an empty row for each iteration of the inner loop?

Comment: @TomMcLean, yes